# Gmapping overwrites map

Tags: ros, navigation, p2os, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a simulation with p2os package and I built my own map (a simple map, with some walls) in order to check if everything was going well. When I start moving the robot, the map is done correctly at the beginning, but when I drive the robot out of the main room, the generated map gets wrong. We obtain something like different parts of the map in wrong places, overwriting one each other. Does anybody know why it is happening?

(obs: I'm building a 2D map with a laser scanner)

Original map:

[image: Original]

Original map:

[image: Map]

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47185/gmapping-overwrites-map/) by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-31**:
The image link doesn't work. From the description it might just be the case that gmapping failed.

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2012-11-01**:
thanks, I have fixed it. I'm new at ROS so I don't know if this map is considered complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your images, it looks like something wrong with the rotation odometry. [GMapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping) can usually close loops for small rotational errors, but once that gets large, the map will mess up badly.

Have you run through these yet?

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you hand us your map it would be easier to answer but I guess that the problem is simple yet hard to correct:

Your environment may be a bit complex and have one or several loops which is a common problem in SLAM algorithms. You can see here that it is a problem that is currently being addressed by many researchers http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=slam+loop+closing

I suggest that instead of using one 180degree laser you use two and that you should lower down your robot speed.

Hope this helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) with karma: 483 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-02**:
From the structure in the images it doesn't seem too complex given that the laser range is sufficient to cover the area.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This scenario looks like you should be able to get good results with [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping) (at least if your LIDAR ist not severly range-limited). You should be able to use it as a drop-in replacement for gmapping as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot#Use_in_place_of_gmapping). Can now also be installed via packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-hector-slam
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2012-11-06**:
I have to use gmapping in this project, sorry.